# Jmeter Viewstates

Tags: asp.net, jmeter, viewstate

I have j meter setup

```
TestPlan
   ThreadGroup
   HTTP CacheManager
   HTTP CookieManager
   RegularEpression  Extractor id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.+?)"
   RegularExpression Extractor  id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="(.+?)"
     RecordingController 
          login ${VIEWSTATE}
          browsingForminmyapp.aspx ${VIEWSTATE}
          browsingForm2inmyapp.aspx  ${VIEWSTATE}
```

Everything works as expected, **but**, I would like to set up OnceOnlyController so that my login form gets executed only the number of times as I set Number of threads in my ThreadGroup. If i create this OnceOnly controller, my ViewStates are not getting right and i GET redirrect, object moved, invalid VIEWSTATE. 
This would be the setup that is not working, but gets my login form executed right number of times.

```
TestPlan
   ThreadGroup
   HTTP CacheManager
   HTTP CookieManager
   RegularEpression  Extractor id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.+?)"
   RegularExpression Extractor  id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="(.+?)"
     RecordingController
          OnceOnlyController
            login.aspx ${VIEWSTATE}
      browsingForminmyapp.aspx ${VIEWSTATE}
      browsingForm2inmyapp.aspx ${VIEWSTATE}
```

How can I get it work as it works using first setup, but after creating once only controller things are getting messy, VIEWSTATES are not OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest putting your `login.aspx` sampler under [If Controller](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie). Use the following statement as "Condition"

```
${__BeanShell(vars.getIteration()==1)}
```

- [__Beanshell()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell) function - allows executing arbitrary Beanshell script
- [vars.getIteration()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#getIteration()) - method which returns current loop number (on thread group level)

Also move your Regular Expression Extractor elements to be children of your `login.aspx` request elsewise they will be applied to each and every sampler causing additional overhead.